# event.target.nodeName != "CHECKBOX"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get a function work properly.
When clicking on a row in a table, a pop up appears with the info(from the clicked row) auto filled in into textfields. This part works perfectly.

What i want to do now is that the function gets called ONLY if in the row it's not clicked on a button or a checkbox.
The button part works, but not the checkbox.

It seems that *event.target.nodeName != "CHECKBOX"* isn't working.

Why doesn't he recognize the nodeName "checkbox"? Or am i doing it wrong ? I already searched the internet to find the nodeName for a checkbox. But no results :/

Sorry for my bad English!

```
    $('.management table.table-companies tbody tr').on('click touchstart',function(event) {
        if(
            event.target.nodeName != "BUTTON" 
            && event.target.nodeName != "I"
            && event.target.nodeName != "CHECKBOX"
            )
        {

            jmOpenRelatedContact($(this));

        }
    });
```

Comment: Because the nodeName of `<input type="checkbox"/>` is "INPUT", not "CHECKBOX".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `event.target.type` instead of  `event.target.nodeName` for input.

See the code:

```js
var ctype = document.getElementById("c").type;
document.write("type="+ctype)
```

```html
<input id="c" type="checkbox">
```

Answer (score 2):

If you allow clicks on inputs that are not checkboxes, using `nodeName != "INPUT"` won't be right. In this case, you can use `getAttribute()` to find out if the type is "checkbox":

```
$('.management table.table-companies tbody tr').on('click touchstart',function(event) {
    if(
        event.target.nodeName != "BUTTON" 
        && event.target.nodeName != "I"
        && !(event.target.nodeName == "INPUT" && event.target.getAttribute('type') == "checkbox")
        )
    {

        jmOpenRelatedContact($(this));

    }
});
```

**Edit:** Check out [RoliCo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29042677/1913729)'s answer, it's a good one.

Answer (score 0):

The node name is 'INPUT', because a checkbox is defined like the following :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="animal" value="Cat" />
^^^^^
We are using an input element.
```

You could have figured that out by alerting the value of

```
event.target.nodeName
```

**See by yourself : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/vnu4jb3e/1/)**